# Use openvino from docker

Tags: docker, openvino

I am trying to use OpenVINO from docker container. 
I use docker file from official web site https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_docker_linux.html

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
USER root
WORKDIR /
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-xo", "pipefail", "-c"]
# Creating user openvino
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash openvino && \
    chown openvino -R /home/openvino
ARG DEPENDENCIES="autoconf \
                  automake \
                  build-essential \
                  cmake \
                  cpio \
                  curl \
                  gnupg2 \
                  libdrm2 \
                  libglib2.0-0 \
                  lsb-release \
                  libgtk-3-0 \
                  libtool \
                  udev \
                  unzip \
                  dos2unix"
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ${DEPENDENCIES} && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /thirdparty
RUN sed -Ei 's/# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get source ${DEPENDENCIES} && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# setup Python
ENV PYTHON python3.6
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-dev lib${PYTHON}=3.6.9-1~18.04 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG package_url=ARG package_url=http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16612/l_openvino_toolkit_p_2020.2.120.tgz
ARG TEMP_DIR=/tmp/openvino_installer
WORKDIR ${TEMP_DIR}
ADD ${package_url} ${TEMP_DIR}
# install product by installation script
ENV INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR /opt/intel/openvino
RUN tar -xzf ${TEMP_DIR}/*.tgz --strip 1
RUN sed -i 's/decline/accept/g' silent.cfg && \
    ${TEMP_DIR}/install.sh -s silent.cfg && \
    ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/install_dependencies/install_openvino_dependencies.sh
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN rm -rf ${TEMP_DIR}
# installing dependencies for package
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN ${PYTHON} -m pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools && \
    find "${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/" -type f -name "*requirements*.*" -path "*/${PYTHON}/*" -exec ${PYTHON} -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r "{}" \; && \
    find "${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/" -type f -name "*requirements*.*" -not -path "*/post_training_optimization_toolkit/*" -not -name "*windows.txt"  -not -name "*ubuntu16.txt" -not -path "*/python3*/*" -not -path "*/python2*/*" -exec ${PYTHON} -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r "{}" \;
WORKDIR ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/accuracy_checker
RUN source ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/bin/setupvars.sh && \
    ${PYTHON} -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/accuracy_checker/requirements.in && \
    ${PYTHON} ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/accuracy_checker/setup.py install
WORKDIR ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/tools/post_training_optimization_toolkit
RUN if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then \
        ${PYTHON} -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/tools/post_training_optimization_toolkit/requirements.txt && \
        ${PYTHON} ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/tools/post_training_optimization_toolkit/setup.py install; \
    fi;
# Post-installation cleanup and setting up OpenVINO environment variables
RUN if [ -f "${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}"/bin/setupvars.sh ]; then \
        printf "\nsource \${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/bin/setupvars.sh\n" >> /home/openvino/.bashrc; \
        printf "\nsource \${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/bin/setupvars.sh\n" >> /root/.bashrc; \
    fi;
RUN find "${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/" -name "*.*sh" -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
USER openvino
WORKDIR ${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But if I try to launch python program with this line:

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore
```

It writes ModuleNotFoundError, No module named 'openvino'. I tried to source file setupvars.sh with these commands, but it doesn't help.

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh"
RUN source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
```

What should I do to use openvino python apps from docker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are building the Docker image, and trying to run the OpenVINO Python apps outside the docker image it won't work. You can create the Docker image and run Docker image interactively to execute the Python apps within the image. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ for more information on `docker run`.

Couple of issues noticed in your Dockerfile when used in my environment. After the changes and steps below, you should be able to import *openvino* module and run a Python application:

In Dockerfile line #34:

```
// Before:
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-dev lib${PYTHON}=3.6.9-1~18.04 && \
// After:
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-dev lib${PYTHON} && \
```

In Dockerfile line #36:

```
// Before:    
ARG package_url=ARG package_url=http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16612/l_openvino_toolkit_p_2020.2.120.tgz
// After:   
ARG package_url=http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/16612/l_openvino_toolkit_p_2020.2.120.tgz
```

After the changes above, run `docker build . -t <image-name>` (i.e. *docker build . -t openvino-ubuntu*) to build Docker image. If successful you would see `Successfully built bf2280a70ffd Successfully tagged openvino-<image-name>:latest`.

Then run image interactively with `docker run -it <image_name>` (i.e. *docker run -it openvino-ubuntu*). You would see something similar to:

```
[setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized
openvino@ce618ea2bc47:/opt/intel/openvino_2020.2.120$
```

To verify Python is able to import *IECore* from *openvino* module, test with Python interpreter:

```
openvino@ce618ea2bc47:/opt/intel/openvino_2020.2.120$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from openvino.inference_engine import IECore
>>>
```

To run OpenVINO Python app, test one of the sample apps in */opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/python*, for example *object_detection_sample_ssd.py*:

```
openvino@ce618ea2bc47:/opt/intel/openvino_2020.2.120$ python3 /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/python/object_detection_sample_ssd/object_detection_sample_ssd.py

usage: object_detection_sample_ssd.py [-h] -m MODEL -i INPUT [INPUT ...]
                                  [-l CPU_EXTENSION] [-d DEVICE]
                                  [--labels LABELS] [-nt NUMBER_TOP]
object_detection_sample_ssd.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--model, -i/--input
```

Answer (score 0):

what `setupvars.sh` does is essentially export environment variables that makes OpenVINO works correctly, to be specific:

1. append openvino python modules path to PYTHONPATH so python interpreter knows where to find `openvino` package (all the python sources).
2. append openvino shared library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH so any `.so` file the openvino runtime depends on can be found by system dynamic linker.

`source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh` modifies environment variable for current bash process executing the command line and all children processes invoked later on from the same bash interpreter (inherit parent processes enviroment variable)

but in Dockerfile, the RUN directives [execute commands differently](https://vsupalov.com/set-dynamic-environment-variable-during-docker-image-build/), each command is executed in separate container and only impact on image is saved across commands, any modification to environment variables are lost.

later on after docker image was built and you try to start a container from it and use openvino inside that container, you have to run `source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh` in that console instead before using openvino.

But you can avoid such a tedious step by putting this command into `/root/.bashrc` in the docker image, so the bash shell invoked from container executes it automatically for you. that's also what most openvino dockerfile does:

```
RUN echo "source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh" >> /root/.bashrc
```

check [this](https://github.com/mateoguzman/openvino-docker/blob/master/sample-app/Dockerfile#L121) and [this](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/docker_ci/blob/master/dockerfiles/ubuntu20/build_custom/Dockerfile#L133)

By the way, typically a python package should not depending on sourcing some script for it to work correctly, standard python package would copy the python source into standard location and all shared object files are using RPATH/RUN_PATH to address dynamic linking issue(w/o installing so files into /usr/lib). for example if you install openvino by pip, this step would not needed.